# Closed subset of metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space with $p \in X$ a point, $C \subset X$ a subset.
Show $C$ is closed iff $C \cap \overline{B_R(p)}$ is closed for any $R>0$.

Supposing $C$ is closed is pretty easy as intersecting it with closed ball is still closed.

So then assume $C \cap \overline{B_R(p)}$ is closed (so it equals its closure) and want to show $C$ is closed, i.e., $C = \overline{C}$.

Is this the way to go about it? Clearly $C \subset \overline{C}$, so we wish to show $\overline{C} \subset C$ but taking $x \in \overline{C}$ and showing $x \in C$?

Because then $x$ is a limit point of $C$ so any open ball (for any choice of $R>0$) centered at $p$ intersects $C$ nontrivially? Am I on the right track? Just a hint will suffice not an entire solution. Thanks!

Comment: the only thing that worries me about what you are saying, is that it does not seem to involve the arbitrary radius $R$

Comment: Yes, I agree with 311411, you are on the right bath, but you can not drop the assumption $R$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @Hossien Sahebjame Is $C$ bounded ? If $C$ is bounded then the proof is easy: choose $R>0$ large enough so that $C\subset B_{R}(p)$ and consequently $C\cap B_{R}(p)=C$ is closed :)

Comment: @Medo no not bounded lol, ironically I thought the EXACT same thing initially, since $C$ is a subset of the ball, the intersection is closed but I don't have that $C$ is bounded unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks guys, that is the subtly I was worried most about Was arbitrariness of $R$, so this allows for any choice of $R$?

Comment: maybe $d(p,x)$ is important. For consider the example X = real line, with C = $[0,2] \setminus 1$, while $p=5$.

Comment: @Medo Im sorry that confused me more, are you swaying away from my initial question? So you're saying intersection can be closed when one component is not closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose $x$ is a limit point for $C$, but maybe not an element of $C$. Let $R\,=\,d(p,x)\,+\,5.$ By hypothesis, the set

$$C\,\cap\,\overline{B_R(p)}\,\cap\,\overline{B_1(x)}$$

is closed.  There is a sequence in $C$ that converges to $x$. This sequence is ultimately in the unit ball at $x$, and we have made $\overline{B_R(p)}$ big enough to include that unit ball. The triple intersection above is closed, so contains all of its limit points. Hence $x$ belongs to $C$.

Comment: omg wow thanks!!!!!! question, what guarantees the sequence to be inside of the unit ball at $x$?

Comment: Also can you make the 5 a 1 and it would still work?

Comment: actually i think the $5$ is important because we work in a very general abstract metric space. Remember that such spaces can be very anti-intuitive. For example $B(x,r) \subsetneq \overline{B(x,r)} \subsetneq \overline{B}(x,r) \ $ can occur. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/proper-inclusion-between-open-ball-closure-of-open-ball-and-the-closed-ball-in?rq=1

Comment: Because of the fact that we may not have PROPER containment, correct? So you make it at least 2 just to guarantee proper containment

Comment: on second thought, I think that replacing the 5 with a 1 will be ok! Because (check this)  $B_1(x) \subset B_{1\,+\,d(x,p)}(p)$. From this $\overline{B_1(x)} \subset \overline{B_{1\,+\,d(x,p)}(p)}$ follows.

Comment: Question, could we replace the number with any $\epsilon >0$ so you basically choose $R$ big enough so that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset B_R(p)$ then this forces $x \in C$.

Comment: I think so. There is nothing magical about a radius of one.

Comment: cool thanks I finally got it 100% down! thank you a million